# Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: php, apache

I am facing the problem while adding my own php file into a word press theme. While executing the file I am getting the following error:

> "Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object.
> It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 403
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 "

Comment: You need to fix the access rights. Turn to your hosting provider to find out how.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems you are your own provider. Try `man chmod` in the console (assuming Linux) or see if your favorite file manager supports that.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have any .htaccess file in the folder. May be there itself it is creating problem for you.